# How to rename multiple files at once using terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, file-rename

I have a bunch of data files that are zipped (they all end in '**.tagAlign.gz**').

I want to move the first 100,000 lines of each file into a new file that is not zipped and keep the name of each file as it is.

I've done this for one file at a time before, but in this case I have probably 50-100 files.

I've tried looking up commands such as "*rename*" etc but I'm pretty new to all of this and so every answer is too complicated for me to follow.

In the case where I renamed 1 file and moved the first 100,000 lines, this is the command I ran in terminal:

```
gzcat nameoffile.fastq.gz | head -n 400000 > nameoffile_100k.fastq
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but from what I what I *think* you are after, you would need a loop like so:

```
for fn in *.gz; do
    n=$(basename "$fn" .fastq.gz) 
    gzcat "$fn" | head -n 100000 > "$n"_100k.fastq
done
```

(not tested. test nondestructively please...)

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much, and I apologize for the lack of clarity in my question, this is my first time really using stackoverflow!

Comment: Well thanks! Please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you out.